# Mysql JSON EXTRACT don't work with large key

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I'm trying to check if key-value exist in a JSON document in mysql. This is the query I use:

SELECT (JSON_EXTRACT(saved_stuff, '$.key') IS NOT NULL) FROM table

Now when the key is "test" it works great. It returns either 0 or 1, depending on whether the document exists. When the key is "34f8d790-6e25-4f31-ae8a-a17c04c96045" I get the error:
"Error: Query failed: ER_INVALID_JSON_PATH: Invalid JSON part expression. The error is around character position 38"

I'm thinking it has something to do with the length of the key, but I'm not sure. Please, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [11.5 The JSON Data Type :: Searching and Modifying JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-paths):

> ...
>
> - ... The key name must be specified within double quotation marks
>   if the name without quotes is not legal within path expressions (for
>   example, if it contains a space).
>
> ...

Try:

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(
    `saved_stuff`,
    '$."34f8d790-6e25-4f31-ae8a-a17c04c96045"'
  ) IS NOT NULL
FROM
  `table`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00ffcdf91442826ea3671a3ce6927735).